# Swift Modeling Friend System

Tags: swift, rest

I'm making a simple app in swift, and have users, photos, and friends table in Postgres and store photos in S3. The app functions with simple REST calls. I'm having an issue with the following:
User A sends a friend request to User B
    Friend Table: sender_id: UserA_id, receiver_id: UserB_id, status: 'pending'
Now, on the device, UserB is added to UserA's pendingFromMe's friends. Now, how at the same time do I update UserB's pendingToMe's friends **on a separate device**?

A couple options I have thought of

- Postgres Listen - This is bad as 500 connection limit means this won't work
- APN would send a Push Notification to UserB and run a function to re-download friends list

Any other options? How would I go about doing this? There are **NO** tutorials outside of Parse/Firebase and I don't want to use BaaS since I've built my own REST server.

Thanks!

*Will accept links to tutorials for this, github repos, etc*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you orchestrate, your facade should call your user service to update the status on both users then invoke the notification service to push to both devices.

If you're event-based, your user service should probably listen to status update events and update the other user's status then fire an event which your notification service should handle to push to the involved devices.

Comment: Hi @clonq, could you elaborate on what you mean by orchestrate? Also, is there a way to subscribe (I.e. Publish ton clients) with Postgres? Basically right now, my client just sends requests to Postgres through my nose backend, but no subscribers.. any tips?

Comment: Service orchestration is the coordination of multiple services from a dedicated service. This service calls other microservices, aggregates the responses and sends the result back to the caller.

Comment: PostgreSQL implements pubsub via [notify/listen](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-notify.html)